# How to join the same table but with different criteria to have multiple result as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table like this (simplified):

```
id|   Country_dsc | Year | Month |   Quantity  | Value |
1 |   Armenia     | 2019 |   2   |      4      |   2   |
2 |   Armenia     | 2019 |   3   |      6      |   4   |
3 |   Armenia     | 2018 |   1   |      6      |   5   |
4 |   Armenia     | 2018 |   2   |      3      |   3   |
5 |   Armenia     | 2018 |   3   |      7      |   5   |
```

And I would like to have a result like this:

```
  Name        | YTD_Quantity_Y | YTD_Quantity_LY | YTD_Value_Y | YTD_Value_LY | 
  Armenia     |       10       |        16       |      6      |     13       |
```

with `YTD_Quantity_Y` being the sum of all quantity of 2019 and `YTD_Quantity_LY` the sum of all the quantity of 2018 from the begining of the year until the current month (in this example, March). Same logic for the Value.

So what I tried was:

```
SELECT t1.Country_Dsc as Name,
        SUM(t1.Quantity) as YTD_Quantity_Y, -- January, February, March 2019
        SUM(t2.Quantity) as YTD_Quantity_LY -- January, February, March 2018
        SUM(t2.Value) as YTD_Value_Y  -- January, February, March 2019
        SUM(t2.Value) as YTD_Value_LY -- January, February, March 2018
FROM example_table t1
     LEFT JOIN example_table t2 on t1.Country_Dsc = t2.Country_Dsc
                                AND t1.Year = 2018 
                                AND t1.Month = t2.Month
WHERE t1.Year = 2019
      and t1.Month <= 3 -- in this case I want all data from January to March for 2019 and 2018 
GROUP BY t1.Country_Dsc
```

The problem is that since 2019 have no record for January, I don't get the quantity of January 2018 in *YTD_Quantity_LY*.

If I start from 2018 and join on 2019 it works but sometimes I have the case where it's for 2018 that I don't have the record for a month so it'll not show for 2019 (*YTD_Quantity_Y*).

Is-it possible to have the result I desire without using a query for each year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, Country_dsc varchar(10), [Year] int, [Month] int, Quantity int, [Value] int );
insert into @tbl values
(1 , 'Armenia' , 2019 , 2 , 4 , 2 ),
(2 , 'Armenia' , 2019 , 3 , 6 , 4 ),
(3 , 'Armenia' , 2018 , 1 , 6 , 5 ),
(4 , 'Armenia' , 2018 , 2 , 3 , 3 ),
(5 , 'Armenia' , 2018 , 3 , 7 , 5 )

select Country_dsc [Name],
       sum(case when year = 2019 then quantity else 0 end) YTD_Quantity_Y ,
       sum(case when year = 2018 then quantity else 0 end) YTD_Quantity_LY ,
       sum(case when year = 2019 then Value else 0 end) YTD_Value_Y ,
       sum(case when year = 2018 then Value else 0 end) YTD_Value_LY 
from @tbl
group by Country_dsc
```

Comment: Of course it was that simple ... Thank you so much for your help ! I feel dumb now haha